# Kendo Grid, draggable

Tags: draggable, kendo-grid

I've implemented the following within my keno grid:
jsfiddle.net/JBeQn/

What I would like to achieve is this; When the user drags a row, any rows beneath it will change style as the dragged row passes over it.

Does anyone have an example of how this can be achieved?

Thanks,

Comment: I guess you resolved your issue since you haven't responded to this in a while.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I'm understanding you right but would this be of help to you?

http://demos.kendoui.com/web/grid/foreignkeycolumn.html

http://demos.kendoui.com/web/grid/column-reordering.html

```
                    reorderable: true,
                    resizable: true,    
                    groupable: true,
```

Comment: Please could you re-read the question and look at the fiddle example.

Comment: @BenWhite Ah I see what you mean, I missed the bit about it being row specific but otherwise I'm still not clear exactly what you want it to do when you say "change style" as the row passes over it, change how?  For example would you want it to highlight each row you hover over as you've selected the row and are dragging it?